# Load LightGBM model from string or buffer

Tags: python, lightgbm

I would like to load a LightGBM model from a string or buffer rather than a file on disk.

It seems that there is a method called `model_from_string` [documentation link](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html#lightgbm.Booster.model_from_string) but ... it produces an error, which seemingly defeats the purpose of the method as I understand it.

```
import boto3
import lightgbm as lgb
import io

model_path = 'some/path/here'
s3_bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('some-bucket')

obj = s3_bucket.Object(model_path)
buf = io.BytesIO()
try:
    obj.download_fileobj(buf)
except Exception as e:
    raise e
else:
    model = lgb.Booster().model_from_string(buf.read().decode("UTF-8"))
```

which produces the following error....

```
TypeError: Need at least one training dataset or model file to create booster instance
```

Alternatively, I thought that I might be able to use the regular loading method

```
lgb.Booster(model_file=buf.read().decode("UTF-8"))
```

... but this also doesn't work.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

Now, I realize that I can create a workaround by writing the buffer to disk, and then reading it. However, this feels very redundant and inefficient.

Thus, my question is, how can instantiate a model to use for prediction without pointing to a an actual file on disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is an undocumented parameter `model_str` which can be used to initialize the `lgb.Booster` object.

```
model = lgb.Booster({'model_str': buf.read().decode("UTF-8")})
```

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/2097#issuecomment-482332232

Credit goes to Nikita Titov aka [StrikerRUS](https://github.com/StrikerRUS) on GitHub.